# Modify native authentication in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm using the out of the box authentication in Laravel 5.2 (using artisan command make:auth). It works like a charm.

Thing is, I'd like to restrict login for only active users (deleted_at = NULL).

However when using soft deletes I cannot retrieve other models with a user_id foreign key (allthough the user has been deleted, I still have to access the users information).

What would be a good approach?

An alternative I came up with is to use an "active" boolean column instead of a "deleted_at" date column. This way, I could filter only user with "active"=TRUE and would have no problem whith foreign keys.

In this case, how could I restrict users to login only if "active" is set to TRUE?

Cheers!

Comment: I don't understand why you would want another column to mimic the `deleted_at` column, your justification doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: If I soft delete with the deleted_at column, I cannot retrieve the users when retrieving other models attached to "users".
Or can I? That would be great

Comment: Well you have the eloquent `withTrashed` and `onlyTrashed` methods to make sure you get results with deleted items or only deleted items. These should serve your purpose fine. You can then use the `trashed` method to detect if a model has been soft deleted.

Comment: Can I use withTrashed when referencing users from another model (for example when quering all active and inactive users from a country point of view)?

And back to the original question: would only "deleted_at" users be able to login?

Answer (score 3):

The trait Laravel uses to authenticate in controllers has a `handleUserWasAuthenticated()` method. It checks for another method called `authenticated()` (which isn’t defined by default) and calls that before fully authenticating a user and letting them access your application. Therefore, if you define this method in your own **AuthController**, you can do any post-authentication checking such as if the user is active.

```php
class AuthController
{
    public function authenticated($request, $user)
    {
        if (! $user->is_active) {
            // Throw exception, display error etc.
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass any extra parameters to the `Auth::attempt()` method, like so:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // Redirect to required route/url
}
```

From what I understand, you can do something similar for the `deleted_at` field as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Auth\AuthController.php, add `authenticated()` function

```
use Auth;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    .
    .
    .

    public function authenticated($request, $user) {
            if (! $user->active) {
                Auth::logout();
                return redirect('login')->withErrors([
                    $this->loginUsername() => 'Your '.$this->loginUsername().' is not active. Please contact Administrators'
                ]);
            }else {
                return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
            }
    }
```